# About Serge Lang's exercise on Hermitian product

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

It asks to find an ortonormal base for the span of those two vectors:

$$A:=(1,i,0), B:=(1,1,1).$$

So, I just remove from $B$ the projection of $B$ over $A$ to get a vector $B'$ ortogonal to $A$...

Me and the solutions book find $B'= 1/2 (1+i, 1-i, 2)$ so before proceed with normalization i tried to verify $\langle A B'\rangle=0$ but i get $\langle A B'\rangle=2$ which means the vectors are not ortogonal! What do i miss?

Comment: I guess you computed the product without taking the complex conjugate of A.

Comment: hum... ...let me ceck...

Comment: seems like i made it correctly if $B'$ is right...    ....$<AB'>=2$

Comment: maybe i got it...

Comment: Good. I wrote an answer in the interim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compute $1\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1+i)+(-i)\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-i)+ 0\cdot 2$. Note the **minus** $i$ This is 
$\frac{1}{2}(1+i) - \frac{1}{2}(i-i^2)=0$.

This assumes you conjugate the first term in the Hermitian product.

Comment: Oh my god im so dumb...  ...i was calculating <BB'> instead <AB'> ...

Comment: Thanks all for the time wasted :|

Comment: Glad to know it is sorted out.